# Cannot assign to read only property 'Status' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: lightning-web-components

```js
handleSubmit() {
    debugger;
    // Prepare the fields to update
    const fields = {};
    fields.Id = this.taskRecord.Id;
    fields.Subject = this.taskRecord.Subject;
    fields.Purpose__c = this.taskRecord.Purpose__c;
    fields.Query_Resolved__c = this.taskRecord.Query_Resolved__c;
    fields.Status = this.taskRecord.Status;
    fields.Call_Category__c = this.taskRecord.Call_Category__c;
    fields.Disposition__c = this.taskRecord.Disposition__c;
    fields.Description = this.taskRecord.Description;

    // Create a record input object
    const recordInput = { fields };

    // Update the record
    updateRecord(recordInput)
        .then(() => {
            // Show a success toast message
            const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Task updated successfully',
                variant: 'success',
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);

            // Switch back to the table view
            this.showForm = false;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // Handle error and show an error toast message
            console.error(error);
            const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error',
                message: 'Error updating task',
                variant: 'error',
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
        });
}
```

Comment: Please use [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/410499/edit) & add additional code that assigns Status property to an object. The method you're showing doesn't seem to have any issues. How do you populate `Status` on `taskRecord` class property? Did it came from parent or @wire call?